# "No provider for service" in APP_INITIALIZER factory

Tags: angular

In my backend, I have some API resources which return some configuration information to the frontend. Since I don't want to call them for each resource I show, I want to do it upfront.

From what I've seen, APP_INITIALIZER looks promising, so I tried it: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-4yfvtk?file=src%2Flink.service.ts
But it is not able to inject the `LinkService`.

I added the service with deps to the AppModule. I am not quite sure what the issue is. Furthermore, I've checked other topics, but as far as I can tell it is the same.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You got it wrong little bit.

First, your `init` funtion must return a function that produces a promise

```
export function initLinkService(service: LinkService) {
  return () =>
    new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      console.log('before init', service);
      service.init();
      console.log('after init', service);
      resolve(null);
    });
}
```

Then you have to actually provide `LinkService` by including it into `providers` section. Moreover, you have to import `HttpClientModule`. Then you provide `init` method directly

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [BrowserModule, FormsModule, HttpClientModule], //import
  declarations: [AppComponent, HelloComponent],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent],
  providers: [
    LinkService, // required provider
    {
      provide: APP_INITIALIZER, 
      useFactory: initLinkService, //pass factory method directly
      deps: [LinkService],
      multi: true,
    },
  ],
```

Now, it will work https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-4yfvtk?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.module.ts

Comment: Thank you! Good point, I missed "//pass factory method directly" also.

Answer (score 2):

There are quite a few adjustments that you need to make in order for this to work:

1. There is no provider for the LinkService, you should either provide it in root using `@Injectable({providedIn: 'root'})` or adding it in the `providers` array of the `AppModule`
2. You need to import `HttpClientModule` in your app module, otherwise there is no provider for `HttpClient` service.
3. The `LinkService` instance will be provided as the first parameter of the topmost function that you use as your factory method. It should look like this:

```
export function initLinkService(service: LinkService) {
  return () =>
    new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      console.log('before init', service);
      service.init();
      console.log('after init', service);
      resolve(null);
    });
}
```

Then the `AppModule` registration changes to this:

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [BrowserModule, FormsModule, HttpClientModule],
  declarations: [AppComponent, HelloComponent],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent],
  providers: [
    LinkService,
    {
      provide: APP_INITIALIZER, 
      useFactory: initLinkService,
      deps: [LinkService],
      multi: true,
    },
  ],
})
```

Comment: That works. Thank you! The inject in root is my local code, but the generator on StackBlitz did not addthat... But it seems that my init factory was wrong.